# Linq to Sql not submitting changes to database file in console app

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, console-application, datacontext

I have an issue with my Linq to SQL Data Context no submitting in my console application.

The following code is all that there is in the main() method.

```
BlogRollerDataContext bdc = new BlogRollerDataContext();
bdc.Urls.InsertOnSubmit(new Url()
    { 
        Approved = false, 
        UrlTo = "http://www.google.com/", 
        UrlFrom = "" 
    });
bdc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Not related to your question: in a case like yours, instantiate the DataContext in a using statement or dispose it after you finished using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://waxtadpole.wordpress.com/2008/05/08/linq-contextsubmitchanges-does-not-add-record-to-database/) might help you.

Comment: But I can pull data from the database, and it only exists on my development laptop, so there is no chance for the connection string to be incorrect.

Comment: Do you see exceptions or the data is just not submitted?

Comment: After reading all the comments I found the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: It was because of the DB being over written each time i would build the application.